# Find redundant pages, files, stored procedures in legacy applications

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, refactoring, legacy-code

I have several horrors of old ASP web applications. Does anyone have any easy ways to find what scripts, pages, and stored procedures are no longer needed? (besides the stuff in "old___code", "delete_this", etc ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are if the stored proc won't run, it isn't being used because nobody ever bothered to update it when sonmething else changed. Table colunms that are null for every single record are probably not being used.

If you have your sp and database objects in source control (and if you don't why don't you?), you might be able to reaach through and find what other code it was moved to production with which should give you a clue as to what might call it. YOu will also be able to see who touched it last and that person might know if it is still needed.

I generally approach this by first listing all the procs (you can get this from the system tables) and then marking the ones I know are being used off the list. Profiler can help you here as you can see which are commonly being called. (But don't assume that because profiler didn't show the proc that it isn't being used, that just gives you a list of the ones to research.) This makes the ones that need to be rearched a much smaller list.  Depending on your naming convention it might be relatively easy to see what part of the code should use them. When researching don't forget that procs are called in places other than the application, so you will need to check through jobs, DTS or SSIS packages, SSRS reports, other applications, triggers etc to be sure something is not being used.

Once you have identified a list of ones you don't think you need, share it with the rest of the development staff and ask if anyone knows if the proc is needed. You'll probably get a a couple more taken off the list this way that are used for something specialized. Then when you have the list, change the names to some convention that allows you to identify them as a candidate for deletion. At the same time set a deletion date (how far out that date is depends on how often something might be called, if it is called something like AnnualXYZReport, then make that date a year out). If  no one complains by the deletion date, delete the proc (of course if it is in source control you can alawys get it back even then).

Onnce you have gone through the hell of identifying the bad ones, then it is time to realize you need to train people that part of the development process is to identify procs that are no longer being used and get rid of them as part of a change to a section of code.  Depending on code reuse, this may mean searching the code base to see if someother part of the code base uses it and then doing the same thing discussed as above, let everyone know it will be deleted on this date, change the name so that any code referncing it will break and then on the date to delete getting rid of it. Or maybe you can have a meta data table where you can put candidates for deletion at the time you know that you have stopped using something and send a report around to everyone once a month or so to determine if anyone else needs it.

I can't think of any easy way to do this, it's just a matter of identifying what might not be used and slogging through.

Comment: Thanks, HLGEM. Most of the *applications* aren't even in source control (yet). Luckily the applications are fairly straightforward asp scripting, no extra components, despite being many hundereds of pages. I was hoping for something that could trawl through my app (a doc generator perhaps?) but I realize this is clutching at straws.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server only, 3 options that I can think of:

- modify the stored procs to log usage
- check if code has no permissions set
- run profiler

And of course, remove access or delete it and see who calls...

Comment: Of course be wary of profiler as it won't catch things that are being used but not everyday (quarterly reports and the like)